# Xamarin Android - add an Intent Filter with empty DataScheme

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nfc, intentfilter, url-scheme

I am trying to add an intent filter to my activity with an empty scheme. The filter looks like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "ClockActivity"), IntentFilter(new[] { "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" },
    Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" }, DataScheme = "")]
```

With this empty scheme i should receive NFC Tags with an url without a scheme. The same example works in Android Studio but i think on xamarin the empty scheme will be ignored.

Do you have any suggestion how to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: go to your obj folder and check the generated manifest file (or unzip the .apk file) and verify if it is really being ignored (I would think it would not ignore it)